# State for not empty EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, state

I use this `selector` for my `EditText`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/mostatil" /><!-- user tap on edit text -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/mostatil50" /><!-- user didn't tap or tap another edit text -->
    <!-- state for not empty edit text -->
</selector>
```

Is there any state for `EditText` that shows `EditText` is not empty (user wrote something in it)?

Answer (score 0):

```
/Just use the below code Snippet/

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:drawable="@drawable/mostatil50" android:state_pressed="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/mostatil" android:state_focused="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/mostatil" />

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if EditText is empty by using the following code:

```
EditText edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
edittext = edittext.getText().toString();
if (edittext.matches("")) {
    //do something here
}
else {
    //do something else
}
```

Comment: thanks,by the code, I should add a listener for all other items in the layout to detect any change. if there is a state for this situation ...

Comment: Sure, for other text related elements, you can use a similar listener. However for state changes related to focus, press, activation etc. you can use XML code directly.

Comment: If this or any other answer solved the question, please consider accepting it.